# How can we achieve ordering in kafka consumer, if we are using multiple message stream(createMessageStreams) within partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, parallel-processing

**Tech Stack:**

1. Kafka ConsumerConnector 2.10
2. kafka Client 0.8.2.2

we want to track the journey of packages. Current we are publishing events on topic **Topic1** from 2 tomcat server with the unique key(trackingNumber) as a ProducerRecord key.

**Publisher:**

```
KafkaProducer<String, TrackingEvent> producer = kafkaProducer.getKafkaProducerForTrackingEvent();
ProducerRecord<String, TrackingEvent> record = new ProducerRecord<>("Topic1",TrackingEvent.getTrackingNumber(), TrackingEvent);
producer.send(record);
```

Event Journey Example for tracking number **TrackingPackage1** for your reference:

open -> In-Tran -> In -> out -> In-Tran -> Del

we know that on a single topic if we are using *n partition, n server* can connect and ordered data consumption starts on every server, But we want to achieve ordered parallelism with the Kafka message stream to maximize the throughput.

**Scenario:**

In our scenario, we have 2 tomcat servers with 2 partitions on a single topic **Topic1**. For *TrackingPackage1* let suppose *P1* allocates, *TrackingPackage2* let suppose *P2* allocates and for *TrackingPackage4* *P1* partition allocates.

If we using a single message stream it will guaranteed order consumption on timestamp basics. 
[image: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/assets/ktdg_04in03.png]
But when we go for more than one stream on that partition there will be no guarantee. Is there any How can we achieve an order guarantee?

**Subscriber:**

```
   private ConsumerConnector consumer;
private ExecutorService   executor;

@Autowired
private IService service;

Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper_connect);
        props.put("group.id", group_id);
        props.put("consumer.id", getHostName());
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", timeout);
        props.put("kafka.topic", topics);

            this.consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig(props));

 Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<>();
 List<String> topicList = StringUtils.split(topics);
 for (String topic : topicList) {
      topicCountMap.put(topic, Integer.parseInt(noOfThreadPerTopics));
}
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(topicList.size() * Integer.parseInt(noOfThreadPerTopics));
for (String topic : topicList) {
List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams) {
    executor.submit(new TrackingPackageKafkaStreamProcessor(stream, service));
    }
}
```

Comment: Order on two partitions is not guaranteed by timestamps. You need one partition to preserve insert order or rethink about how you can process the data out of order that its inserted (for example packages can be bundled together by an order number, and bundles to different destinations don't need chronological ordering). And more than N servers can be used to send data to N servers. And you can use more than one topic to implement your processing logic (order submitted vs order delivery and fulfillment)